# What incantations do I need for the hats to work?

Tags: bug, winterbash

It appears to me that the hats are not working on SFF. I did register for the [hatdash](http://winterba.sh/) and I do have already received [a hat on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/430766/bitmask), but I [made an edit earlier](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/2763/revisions) which should reward [my dear watson](http://winterba.sh/my-dear-watson) but [didn't](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2565/bitmask).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whilst riding a broom, you must chant, "Abracadabra"

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: It [would seem](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/28222/2565) I'm not ... properly equipped for that.

Answer (score 2):

There is a small lag, but you should get it.

To activate it, click on your hats count number

[image: screen-shot]

and select a hat, it will then get a red rectangle around.

[image: screen-shot]

Comment: I don't even have that link on SFF. I do on SO, but not here.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, now that I posted this meta question (not this post, the one above) the dash decided to award me the [most awesome hat imaginable](http://winterba.sh/constantipolitan) so, as far as I'm concerned the thing works. But I'm leaving the question open since the edit was not counted and I suspect it to be a bug.